# Header element is not same size as image inside (header does not have defined height)

Tags: html, css

i'm making this website for a school project, and i can't figure out whats wrong with the header. For some reason there is a small gap at the bottom of the header underneath the image inside it. Despite not giving the header a defined height. Anyone know how to fix this or what the problem is?

HTML:

```
<header id="header-wrap">
    <img class="header-img" src="../images/header-img.png" alt="">
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
   text-align: center;
   grid-area: header;
}
#header-wrap {
   background-color: #212635;
}
.header-img {
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
}
```

This is how it ends up looking:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqurS.jpg)

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: header;
}

#header-wrap {
  background-color: red;
}

.header-img {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header id="header-wrap">
  <img class="header-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqurS.jpg" alt="">
</header>
```

Comment: your question is not fully understandable, please provide a working example, for instance from jsfiddle

Comment: What i want to know is why the header is larger than the image when it has no height. Shouldn't it be the size of the image inside of it by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are displayed inline by default which causes a bit of extra space to be shown below the image as the vertical alignment aligns the bottom of the image with the text baseline. There are a couple of options to fix this:

### Change the display mode to block

To fix it you can set the image to `display: block`. Then you can either center the image using `margin: auto` or make the header a flex container and `justify-content: center`.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: header;
}

#header-wrap {
  background-color: red;
}

.header-img {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<header id="header-wrap">
  <img class="header-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqurS.jpg" alt="">
</header>
```

### Override the default vertical-align

You can also fix the issue by using `vertical-align: bottom` on the image if you want to keep the image inline.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: header;
}

#header-wrap {
  background-color: red;
}

.header-img {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<header id="header-wrap">
  <img class="header-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqurS.jpg" alt="">
</header>
```